# .msi installers freeze with no status showing Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, installation, freeze, installer

I have a slight issue with my laptop. Every time I try to run any sort of a .msi installer to install a application, the status freezes and no progress progresses.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKjL9.png]

I know it is not just the installer because I have tried different .msi installers. I have also run different types of installers though and these seem to work. Help!
 Thanks!

Comment: You can post a link the to the image even with a single reputation point.  You don't have to make the image inline to the question.

Comment: and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you ...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KKjL9.png

Comment: there's the link sorry bout that

Comment: 1. Is it a complete stoppage, or just a long pause (usually while the system tries to make a Restore Point)?  2. Could it be a UAC issue, such as being unable to see a popup requesting authorization (check UAC settings)? See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2012/07/18/disabling-user-account-control-in-windows-8.aspx to turn it off, but only do so **temporarily**.

Comment: Thanks @DrMoishePippik , for your response! It seems to either freeze and completely stop, and not just a long pause. That's what I was sort of thinking, that it was a issue with the popup authorization, but did not think about that possibility more thoroughly. Ok I will check the site and see if it helps but thanks for all your support! I will post a status on the question in comment if this worked :)

Comment: UPDATE: I checked the site and did the instructions, but it still was stuck frozen. I also tried running as administrator option, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you everyone for your help on solving my issue :)**

I had to resort to reinstalling my Windows 8.1 Operating System after searching endlessly online to no avail. My computer has no more issues with the MSIExec now and I hope it doesn't have any more in the future.

Once again,
Thanks ;)